# How to delete review request on phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

Our company uses phabricator as code review process. in last year I created some of code review requests on phabricator. But now I want to delete them. But I am unable to find any button through which I can delete my code review request.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean differential reviews or audit?

Comment: Differential review

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark each diff as `abandon`.

Therefore you have to be the author of a diff. Go to the diff page and change the status. The workflow should be finished now.
[image: status change details]

Comment: If you are not the original author, and the original author cannot do this for some reason, you can "Commandeer Revision" before doing the above.

Comment: Wow that is super unintuitive... the more I use Phabricator the more I don't like it.